# Android Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:design:21.0.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

when i am synchronizing my android project i am getting below error

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:design:21.0.3
Error: Open File
```

i am not getting which library i have to update in Android SDK manager bcz Android support library  21.0.3 is installed but still that error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the Android Support Repository via the SDK manager.

Comment: hi i hv downloded  Android Support Repository  25 and changed build.gradle as  compile 'com.android.support:design:25'      but still its notworking

Comment: 25 is the version of the repository, not the library. You would use at least 22.2.0 as that is when the design library was introduced and a compile SDK of at least 22. Like this `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`